# Django login/ payload visible in plaintext in Chrome DevTools

Tags: python, django, authentication, payload

This is weird. I have created login functions so many times but never noticed this thing.
When we provide a username and password in a form and submit it, and it goes to the server-side as a `Payload` like this, I can see the data in the Chrome DevTools network tab:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken: 
mHjXdIDo50tfygxZualuxaCBBdKboeK2R89scsxyfUxm22iFsMHY2xKtxC9uQNni
username: testuser
password: 'dummy pass' #same as i typed(no encryption)
```

I got this in the case of incorrect creds because the login failed and it wouldn't redirect to the other page.
But then I tried with valid creds and I checked the `Preserve log` box in the Chrome network tab. Then I checked there and I could still see the exact entered `Username` and `password`. At first I thought I might have missed some encryption logic or something.
But then I tried with multiple reputed tech companies' login functionality and I could still see creds in the payload. Isn't this wrong?

It's supposed to be in the encrypted format right?

Models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

html

```
<form method="POST" class="needs-validation mb-4" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-outline mb-4">
       <input type="email" id="txt_email" class="form-control" 
          placeholder="Username or email address" required />
     </div>
  <div class="form-outline mb-4">
        <input type="password" id="txt_password" class="form-control" 
         placeholder="Password" required />
  </div>

                    <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                      <button class="btn btn-primary fa-lg gradient-custom-2 login_btn" type="submit" id="btn_login"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"> </i> Sign in</button>
                      <div class="alert alert-danger" id="lbl_error" role="alert" style="display: none;">

                      </div>

                    </div>

</form>
```

login view

```
def authcheck(request):
    try:
        if request.method == "POST":
            username = request.POST["username"]
            password = request.POST["password"]
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                check_is_partner = Profile.objects.filter(user__username=username, is_partner=True).values("password_reset").first()
                if check_is_partner and check_is_partner['password_reset'] is True:
                    return JsonResponse(({'code':0 ,'username':username}), content_type="json")
                if check_ip_restricted(user.profile.ip_restriction, request):
                    return HttpResponse("ok_ipr", content_type="json")
                login(request, user)
                session = request.session
                session["username"] = username
                session["userid"] = user.id
                session.save()
                if check_is_partner:
                    return HttpResponse("1", content_type="json")
                else:
                    return HttpResponse("ok", content_type="json")
            else:
                return HttpResponse("nok", content_type="json")
    except Exception:
        return HttpResponse("error", content_type="json")
```

Comment: Can you share the view logic? Do you have custom user model?

Comment: @SunderamDubey updated question. i changed a bit to explain the flow in easy way. else im using ajax calls to log in and returning HTTP response depending on the condition.

Comment: So you are using `User` model.

Comment: @SunderamDubey yes

Comment: Can you please share actual code (as you mentioned yiu modified it)?

Comment: Does the main problem you're having is that the `User` model isn't hashing the password?

Comment: You can use [`make_password()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/85b52d22fd2841c34e95b3a80d6f2b668ce2f160/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L72) from `django.contrib.auth.hashers` to hash the password. It takes raw password and converts them to hashed, maybe you can try `authenticate(username=username, password=make_password(password))`, not sure if it'd solve the problem or not.

Comment: @SunderamDubey updated the login function. i think `make_password` is used to convert text into a hashed format while creating/registering user. that hashed value will get stored in db right?

Comment: @SunderamDubey Problem is i entered my creds to login. logged in successfully and it ll redirect me to other page /whatever it depends on logic. but i turned on preserve log(chrome feature F12) to check old logs even after redirect. normally it removes function call logs after redirecting. Where i can see my login function call and payload with username and password exact as a i typed. means without encryption. which is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It's supposed to be in the encrypted format right?

**No.**

What you're seeing in Chrome DevTools is the username and password **before they get encrypted.**

If you were to run [`tcpdump`](https://www.tcpdump.org/) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) when you make the request, you'd see that **it is encrypted over the network**.

In order for the data to be usable by anyone, it has to be unencrypted/decrypted at some point.

For example, you can also see the response data (status code, headers, payload) in Chrome DevTools, which is encrypted over the network, but it's shown to you **after it's been decrypted.**

---

Here's a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16306925/9638991) to a similar question.

---

**EDIT**: This is all assuming you're on a site using `https`. If you're using plain ole `http`, **anyone sniffing the network can see your username + password in plaintext.**

Answer (score 3):

Everything at the front end - the browser side is visible to everyone, and dev tools are no exception. Use HTTPS for security reasons.

Comment: you can see that payload in https also. that's why i was thinking about this that its normal or something to take care of

Comment: Yes, we as a user can see payloads, but someone trying to sniff cannot.

Comment: isn't it wrong? like i can get people's creds for all the sites which are not using any encryption in payload ? Like who's not aware about technology can get scammed in cyber cafes

Comment: Https enables encryption for a connection. Connection between frontend and backend. If you are not using https data transfer in plain text and so it can be sniffed in the middle, in the network. Using https data go to server from frontend in an encryoted form.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that SSL thing. but locally in Dev tools its not protected even its HTTPS. i can simply preserve logs and check auth function call payload with plain text

Comment: only if other websites allow you to run your javascript into their applications or websites. That's why it is also important to manage content security policies for the application. CSP AS commonly known.